# OssContriller cannot upload file to BIM 360

Tags: autodesk-forge

I'm learning forge in viewing my model with BIM 360, it can create bucket, but cannot upload file?

Answer (score 0):

We have a [dedicated tutorial](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/tutorials/document-management/upload-document/) on uploading files to BIM360 in our documentation.